# How to return names of a data list based on condition in r?

Tags: r

I need to remove every element from a data list file with less than 2 rows. So far, I was using the `within` function but since it can be easily 200 rows of a 1200 row list element that doesn't work.

```
datalist <- split(dataframe, f=dataframe$Track)
datalist2 <- within(datalistrm("756", "731",...)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `Filter` in `base R`

```
Filter(\(x) nrow(x) >1, datalist)
```